# Clear quantity field after add to cart is click - Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I want to reset an input field (clear the form) after the button `Add To Cart` is clicked in a WooCommerce single product page.

Any clue?

Comment: Please read [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before posting a question and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: Have you written any code or tried something so far?

Answer (score 0):

In your mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php

Modify the `"input_value"` of woocommerce_quantity_input() by removing the use quantity from POST data.

```
woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
            'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product ),
            'input_value' => $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
        ) );
```

Before:

```
'input_value' => isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( wp_unslash( $_POST['quantity'] ) ) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
```

After:

```
'input_value' => $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),
```